# Test Artifact doesn't appear in Android Studio

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, junit

I've followed all the steps found in this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) and added JUnit

But Test Artifacts doesn't appear in "Build variants" tool window.

How can I display this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of Android Studio, it was 1.0.1
I updated to 1.2.2 and the problem is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an answer but for me it is different case .Since I installed Beta version android studio 2.0, I didn't see Artifact in build variants.For me using stable version instead of beta solve the issue. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 2.0, you have to uncheck this: "Enable all test artifacts (Unit Test and Instrumentation Test) in Android projects".

markproxy provided the solution in this link, [Test Artifact selector missing/gone from Build Variants in Android Studio 2 Beta 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708263/test-artifact-selector-missing-gone-from-build-variants-in-android-studio-2-beta)